# How JavaScript handles for statements

Tags: javascript

This is really a question about JavaScript effeciency, and I may be missing the point. Regardless, say you define a for statement like so: `for (var i = 0; i<10; i++){...}`. Each time the for statement loops round, does it check the for statement's parameters every loop? For more clarification, lets say we use a function which returns a random number, and we use it as our condition in the for loop like so:

```
function test(){
    var z = /*NEW RANDOM VALUE*/;
    return z;
}
for (var i = 0; i<test();i++){
    ...
}
```

Would the test() function get called every loop, or just once?

**Edit:**

Thanks for your all your support, I was in essence unsure if defining a variable beforehand for a condition was beneficial within a for loop - which if the condition was called every loop, then defining a variable would be (and is).

Comment: It gets called every iteration

Comment: Why so complicated? Just take `i < 3` as example. This has to be evaluated every iteration, because otherwise the loop wouldn't know whether to stop or not.

Comment: `function() { var z = Math.random()*100; console.log(z); return z; }` and see what happens

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's called at every iteration, although modern Javascript engines are trying to optimize all kinds of things. It was a common Javascript pattern to cache the length of a Javascript array, as the first implementations were slow.

```
var l=arr.length;
for (var i=0; i<l; i++) { /*...*/ }
```

Answer (score 2):

I just used the following code, which answers my own question: yes every loop the condition gets checked. Here's what I used to test this:

```
function rand(){
    console.log("rand() called.");
    return Math.floor((Math.random()*10)+1);
}
for (var i = 0;i<rand();i++){
    console.log("Loop: "+i);
}
```

Result:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Yes, the condition is checked every time.  If you were to write the below, arr.length will be calculated each time.

```
var arr = ['cat', 'dog', 'llama'];

for (var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
  console.log(arr[i]);
}
```

Instead, it is more efficient to write the below, since arr.length will only be calculated once.

```
var arr = ['cat', 'dog', 'llama'];
var len = arr.length;
for (var i = 0; i < len; i++) {
  console.log(arr[i]);
}
```

Comment: Note that `arr.length` is not calculated, it's a "static" value that gets updated when the array is mutated. Also, browsers got really good optimizing `for (var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {`, so the statement that the other way is faster may not be true anymore.